Haar measure and convolution on a Lie subgroup
Let $G$ be a Lie group and $H \leq G$ a closed Lie subgroup.

Take Haar measures $dg$ and $dh$ on $G$ and $H$. Can we get $dh$ from $dg$ (up to some constant)? I would also like to understand it in the sense of distributions (generalized functions).
How should one interpret the convolution $dh *_G \chi$ with $\chi$ a smooth function on $G$. Here, the convolution is on $G$, i.e. for appropriate functions on $G$ we have $\varphi *_G \chi (x) = \int_G \varphi(y) \chi(y^{-1}x) dg(y)$.

